# XSLT sum of nodes by parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with an XSLT: I like to compute the sum of nodes by a parameter.

The XML source looks like this:

```
<Documents>
  <Document>
    <Deleted>0</Deleted>
    <DocumentType>2</DocumentType>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <CurrencyRate>4.368400</CurrencyRate>
    <GrossValue>1000.00</GrossValue>
    <DeliveryDate>2016-08-01</DeliveryDate>
    <FormOfPayment>2</FormOfPayment>
    <DueDate>2016-09-28</DueDate>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <Deleted>0</Deleted>
    <DocumentType>2</DocumentType>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <CurrencyRate>4.368400</CurrencyRate>
    <GrossValue>2000.00</GrossValue>
    <DeliveryDate>2016-08-05</DeliveryDate>
    <FormOfPayment>5</FormOfPayment>
    <DueDate>2016-09-05</DueDate>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <Deleted>0</Deleted>
    <DocumentType>2</DocumentType>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <CurrencyRate>4.368400</CurrencyRate>
    <GrossValue>3000.00</GrossValue>
    <DeliveryDate>2016-08-30</DeliveryDate>
    <FormOfPayment>2</FormOfPayment>
    <DueDate>2016-10-29</DueDate>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <Deleted>0</Deleted>
    <DocumentType>2</DocumentType>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <CurrencyRate>4.368400</CurrencyRate>
    <GrossValue>2500.00</GrossValue>
    <DeliveryDate>2016-08-26</DeliveryDate>
    <FormOfPayment>5</FormOfPayment>
    <DueDate>2016-09-10</DueDate>
  </Document>
</Documents>
```

The result that I need is a sum of amount GrossValue by the parameter `FormOfPayment`.

- So if `FormOfPayment` is 5, the variable `GrossValueCard` should be 4500
- And when `FormOfPayment` is 2, the variable `GrossValueCash` should be 4000.

I tried do this on that way:

```
<xsl:template name="Suma">
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="totalAmount" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentAmount" select="translate($nodes[$index],',','.')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes)=0">
            <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$index=count($nodes)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$totalAmount + $currentAmount"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="Suma">
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index+1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="totalAmount" select="$totalAmount + $currentAmount"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

and it works, but the sum is from all `GrossValue` nodes. Can you give me some advice where I should set a parameter to select the sum by `FormOfPayment`?

I tried to pick this in condition "when" or "if", but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a mathematical formula of your desired result for `GrossValueCard`?

Comment: Result GrossValueCard is a sum every GrossValue nodes from Documents with FormOfPayment 5. Xslt should look at every document and sum nodes GrossValue to variable for example name GrossValueCard.

Answer (score 2):

> The result that I need is a sum of amount GrossValue by the parameter
>   `FormOfPayment`.

So why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="FormOfPayment"/>

<xsl:template match="/Documents">
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(Document[FormOfPayment=$FormOfPayment]/GrossValue)"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**ADDED**

If - as it would seem from your attempt - the amounts in the XML source use decimal comma instead of decimal dot (though the XML shown does **not** exhibit this problem), and you are limited to XSLT 1.0, I would suggest you do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="FormOfPayment"/>

<xsl:template match="/Documents">
    <xsl:variable name="amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="Document[FormOfPayment=$FormOfPayment]">
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(GrossValue, ',', '.')"/>
            </amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($amounts)/amount)"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select specific `GrossValue` nodes by using a predicate like `GrossValue[../FormOfPayment = 'x']`.
To add these selected values use the XSLT 1.0 function `sum(...)` with this predicate expression.

A stylesheet could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />

 <xsl:template match="text()" />

 <xsl:template match="/Documents">
   <xsl:variable name="GrossValueCard2">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(Document/GrossValue[../FormOfPayment = '2']/text())" />
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="GrossValueCard5">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(Document/GrossValue[../FormOfPayment = '5']/text())" />
   </xsl:variable>
   Sum of 'FormOfPayment 2's: <xsl:value-of select="$GrossValueCard2" />
   Sum of 'FormOfPayment 5's: <xsl:value-of select="$GrossValueCard5" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. It's so easy, I thought that function sum doesn't work in xslt 1.0, so I make very complicated solution. Thanks for your help one more time:)